# The officer wrote a "code" in my passport

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, passports

Last time I went to the US the officer in the border wrote a "code" in my passport (picture)... What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, you're asking about the part that looks like it reads `SPL 28 OCT 2014 X0530692`?

Comment: When you entered, were you using a visa that had been inserted into another passport?

Comment: Yes Azor! I’m referring to the SPL 28 October 2014/9 X....

Comment: Yes I have 2 passport... and the visa is in the old one! Yes it was issue in Sao Paulo

Comment: @Cami was the visa issued on 28 October 2014?

Answer (score 4):

SPL is the [post code for São Paulo](https://fam.state.gov/fam/09FAM/09FAM010205.html), so this may be an annotation identifying the visa under which you were admitted.

Answer (score 3):

*A Visa was issued on 28 October 2014 at SPL São Paulo on your other passport numbered **K0530692***

That's what was indicated.

That visa granted you the right to report at Port of Entry. Due to one of many possible (valid) reasons you were using a different passport to request entry.